# Deserialize 2 types of XML into same class

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have below 2 formats of XML. Is it possible to have a single class to which I can deserialize both these type of XML data? If so, how should my class definition look like?

```
string xmlText1 = @"<PARM KEY=""K1"" VALUE=""V1""/>";
string xmlText2 = @"<PARM><KEY>K2</KEY><VALUE>V2</VALUE></PARM>";

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PARM")]
public class ParmInfo
{
    [XmlElement("KEY")]
    public string ParmKey { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("VALUE")]
    public string ParmVal { get; set; }

    public ParmInfo()
    {

    }

    public ParmInfo(string inpParmKey, string inpParmVal)
    {
        ParmKey = inpParmKey;
        ParmVal = inpParmVal;
    }
}
```

Above class will work with xmlText2. How should I modify it to handle both xmlText1 and xmlText2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I finally ended up doing. I was hoping to avoid this. But, anyway.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PARM")]
public class ParmInfo
{
    private string _ParmName;
    private string _ParmVal;
    private bool _UsingAttr = false;

    [XmlElement("KEY", IsNullable = true)]
    public string ParmName
    {
        get
        {
            return _ParmName;
        }
        set
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                _ParmName = value;
                _UsingAttr = false;
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("VALUE", IsNullable = true)]
    public string ParmVal
    {
        get
        {
            return _ParmVal;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                _ParmVal = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("KEY")]
    public string ParmNameAttr
    {
        get
        {
            return _ParmName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                _ParmName = value;
                _UsingAttr = true;
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("VALUE")]
    public string ParmValueAttr
    {
        get
        {
            return _ParmVal;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                _ParmVal = value;
            }
        }
    }


    public ParmInfo()
    {

    }

    public ParmInfo(string inpParmName, string inpParmVal)
    {
        ParmName = inpParmName;
        _ParmVal = inpParmVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want single class for both XMLs

```
string xmlText1 = @"<PARM KEY=""K1"" VALUE=""V1""/>";
string xmlText2 = @"<PARM><KEY>K2</KEY><VALUE>V2</VALUE></PARM>";

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PARM")]
public class ParmInfo
{
    [XmlAttribute("KEY")]
    public string ParmAttrKey { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("VALUE")]
    public string ParmAttrVal { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("KEY")]
    public string ParmEleKey { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("VALUE")]
    public string ParmEleVal { get; set; }

    public ParmInfo()
    {

    }

    public ParmInfo(string inpParmEleKey, string inpParmEleVal, string inpParmAttrKey, string inpParmAttrVal)
    {
        ParmEleKey = inpParmEleKey;
        ParmEleVal = inpParmEleVal;
        ParmAttrKey = inpParmAttrKey;
        ParmAttrVal = inpParmAttrVal;
    }
}
```

This is what I used for serializing

```
string xmlText1 = @"<PARM KEY=""K1"" VALUE=""V1""/>";
string xmlText2 = @"<PARM><KEY>K2</KEY><VALUE>V2</VALUE></PARM>";

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ParmInfo));

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlText1);
var xmlText1Serialized = (ParmInfo)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

stringReader = new StringReader(xmlText2);
var xmlText2Serialized = (ParmInfo)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the intent is not to have 2 separate set of properties in the class. Using either of XML format should mean the same once its serialized into this object. But it gave me some idea.